# If number >= 24, get next number divisible by 12

Tags: c#, math

I'm working on an inventory system for a game.

If the player inventory is empty or has less than 24 items, I want show 36 slots.

If the inventory has 24 or more items, I want to find the next number divisible by 12 and use that. Basically I always want to allow at least 12 extra slots, with a minimum of 36 total.

Here's the code I've tried which is not giving me desired results:

```
    int testInventoryCount = 29;
    int itemSlotCount = 36;
    int itemSlotCount2 = 36;
    int itemSlotCount3 = 36;

    if (testInventoryCount >= 24)
    {
        itemSlotCount = ((testInventoryCount / 12) + 1) * 12;
        itemSlotCount2 = (testInventoryCount + 12) - (testInventoryCount % 12);
        itemSlotCount3 = (testInventoryCount + 12 / 2) / 12 * 12;
    }

    Debug.Log(testInventoryCount);
    Debug.Log(itemSlotCount);
    Debug.Log(itemSlotCount2);
    Debug.Log(itemSlotCount3);
```

None of them are giving me the correct value.

For example, this is what I want:

```
If the inventory has 0 items, have 36 slots.
If the inventory has 20 items, have 36 slots.
If the inventory has 26 items, have 48 slots.
If the inventory has 30 items, have 48 slots.
If the inventory has 34 items, have 48 slots.
If the inventory has 60 items, have 72 slots.
If the inventory has 66 items, have 84 slots.
```

Etc...

I'm terrible at math. Halp.

Comment: Please update your example to show what the slots should be if the inventory is 12, 24, 36 and 48.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple function for getting the number of necessary slots.

```
public static int get_slot_count(int item_count)
{
    return Math.Max(36,(item_count / 12 + 2) * 12);
}
```

I tested and get the following results.

```
0 items / 36 slots
1 items / 36 slots
2 items / 36 slots
3 items / 36 slots
4 items / 36 slots
5 items / 36 slots
6 items / 36 slots
7 items / 36 slots
8 items / 36 slots
9 items / 36 slots
10 items / 36 slots
11 items / 36 slots
12 items / 36 slots
13 items / 36 slots
14 items / 36 slots
15 items / 36 slots
16 items / 36 slots
17 items / 36 slots
18 items / 36 slots
19 items / 36 slots
20 items / 36 slots
21 items / 36 slots
22 items / 36 slots
23 items / 36 slots
24 items / 48 slots
25 items / 48 slots
26 items / 48 slots
27 items / 48 slots
28 items / 48 slots
29 items / 48 slots
30 items / 48 slots
31 items / 48 slots
32 items / 48 slots
33 items / 48 slots
34 items / 48 slots
35 items / 48 slots
36 items / 60 slots
37 items / 60 slots
38 items / 60 slots
39 items / 60 slots
40 items / 60 slots
41 items / 60 slots
42 items / 60 slots
43 items / 60 slots
44 items / 60 slots
45 items / 60 slots
46 items / 60 slots
47 items / 60 slots
48 items / 72 slots
49 items / 72 slots
```

I am curious why you need more than 36 slots for 24 items. If you just need extra 12 slots, the following would be better and gives more reasonable results.

```
public static int get_slot_count(int item_count)
{
    return Math.Max(36,((item_count - 1) / 12 + 2) * 12);
}
```

Test results.

```
0 items / 36 slots
1 items / 36 slots
2 items / 36 slots
3 items / 36 slots
4 items / 36 slots
5 items / 36 slots
6 items / 36 slots
7 items / 36 slots
8 items / 36 slots
9 items / 36 slots
10 items / 36 slots
11 items / 36 slots
12 items / 36 slots
13 items / 36 slots
14 items / 36 slots
15 items / 36 slots
16 items / 36 slots
17 items / 36 slots
18 items / 36 slots
19 items / 36 slots
20 items / 36 slots
21 items / 36 slots
22 items / 36 slots
23 items / 36 slots
24 items / 36 slots
25 items / 48 slots
26 items / 48 slots
27 items / 48 slots
28 items / 48 slots
29 items / 48 slots
30 items / 48 slots
31 items / 48 slots
32 items / 48 slots
33 items / 48 slots
34 items / 48 slots
35 items / 48 slots
36 items / 48 slots
37 items / 60 slots
38 items / 60 slots
39 items / 60 slots
40 items / 60 slots
41 items / 60 slots
42 items / 60 slots
43 items / 60 slots
44 items / 60 slots
45 items / 60 slots
46 items / 60 slots
47 items / 60 slots
48 items / 60 slots
49 items / 72 slots
```